# $q deferred not firing continuations in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I am creating some unit tests that work with promises which I want to resolve manually and am finding that my promise continuations seem never to be hit. So I open up the console in my jasmine debug panel, put a reference to `$q` on the window object...and

```
d = $q.defer()
d.promise.then(x => console.log(`done`, x))
d.resolve(5)
```

Nothing gets logged...

[image: $q seems to never trigger continuations]

What is going on?! Is `$q` somehow now working? Does it not work like every other deferred implementation in the world works? Am I reading their ([insanely meager](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)) documentation wrong? How is it possible for the above promise to be resolved but not have its continuation fire?!

AngularJs 1.5.8

Comment: Don't Jasmine tests need to invoke `$rootScope.$apply()`?

Comment: @georgeawg huh? is `$q` for some reason tied into the message digest? I just assumed it wouldn't be because...for chrissake, there is no reason on this earth for it to be.

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript.

Comment: @georgeawg I know all that, but a promise continuation is literally just "here, when that is done, run this code" with deferreds it has nothing to do with scope at all! I realize why you need `$apply` for anything that will change DOM, but promise continuations don't do that! They just are more code. I had assumed that when the promise resolved it would execute all handlers and then call `$apply()` to flush changes, I didn't realize that *another* `$apply` would be needed just for handlers to be called. Its a fantastic choice by the Angular team to not document this at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logs `"done 5"` in this example

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($q) {
   var d = $q.defer();
   d.promise.then(x => console.log(`done`, x));
   d.resolve(5);
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Promise example</h1>
  </body>
```

---

### Integration with the browser event loop

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript. Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event.

[image]

ES6 promises are handled by the JavaScript event loop. $q promises are handled by the AngularJS event loop. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

In the case of Jasmine tests, use `$rootScope.$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)

Comment: You were right about the need for `$apply`. I'll mark this as the answer if you want to edit this to say that outside the `run` block (or some other thing that will `$apply` for you) you actually need to do it manually to get even handlers to trigger.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that chart, but what I don't understand is why on earth they would choose to place the execution of continuations in to the angularjs context, and thereby require `$apply()` just to fire them. I can think of no feature or use case this enables that isn't by having it work like everywhere else. Even if you had something a `$watch` somewhere that adds handlers to a promise when triggered...that would *still* work as handlers added to a resolved promise trigger on the next loop. It seems to deviate from the standard in an undocumented way for no benefit at all